# What does WALInitSync actually mean?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pgadmin, database-table

I am using postgresql and pgadmin. I had a table (about 12 million rows) from another database which I wanted to transfer to a table in a new database. So I created a custom backup of that table and tried restore for the new table. The Restore job has been running for a while now (about an hour). In pgadmin's database activity panel, I see:

[image: pg admin database activitity-Sessions]

the activity on the DB table I am trying to restore (`social`) is idle. The active session WAIT event says `WALInitSync`. I looked it up on [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/monitoring-stats.html#WAIT-EVENT-TABLE), it says

```
Waiting for a newly initialized WAL file to reach stable storage.
```

What does this mean? And why is it taking so long?

Comment: The Wait Event just changed to DataFileRead

Comment: Some I/O problem? "sync" is when the file is persisted on disk. If that takes long, it's an indication for an I/O problem.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the high number of rows was the issue for taking so long. It was done by the time I posted this question